# A closed form of a series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I wonder if there is any closed form for the following series 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{2^n}$$

Comment: Please define $[n x]$.  Also, any particular problems?

Comment: @RonGordon the integer part of nx

Comment: Its okay to down vote problems, but it would be nice if you write a reason.

Comment: Not me, but people generally downvote problems they do not feel shows enough explanation/effort.

Comment: Are you aware of the answer if $x$ is an integer?

Comment: @MiloBrandt yes just factor x and the value of the remining serie is welknown

Comment: @MiloBrandt But i do not know even if this function is one to one

Comment: @alexalexeq It would be good to include that calculation in the question; I think this is an interesting question, but it needs some context to be acceptable here.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. For first, we may notice that 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{nx}{2^n} = 2x, \qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
hence the problem boils down to computing:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\{nx\}}{2^n} \tag{1}$$
where $\{\cdot \}$ stands for the fractional part. $\frac{1}{2}-\{z\}$ has a nice Fourier sine series:
$$ \frac{1}{2}-\{z\} = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi m z)}{\pi m} \tag{2}$$
and:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi m n x)}{\pi m 2^n}=\frac{2}{m\pi}\cdot\frac{\sin(2\pi m x)}{5-4\cos(2\pi m x)} \tag{3}$$
so:

> $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\left\lfloor n x\right\rfloor}{2^n}=2x-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2}{m\pi}\cdot\frac{\sin(2\pi m x)}{5-4\cos(2\pi m x)}.\tag{4}$$

The last sum represents a bounded but heavily irregular function: its behaviour is similar to the behaviour of a [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: @alexalexeq: obviously. $\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{2^n}$ is a weakly increasing function for every $n$.